# Blender: disable addon cache

Tags: python, caching, blender

I'm currently coding an add-on for Blender (on OSX, but this shouldn't be relevant).
All my python files are in the default add-on folder. This folder is loaded at Blender's startup and I can see, enable and disable it in User Preferences in Blender.

Now, when I edit my add-on, I simply save the file and hit f8 in Blender to reload all the add-ons. This is kind of working, but sometimes (not always), my changes are not reloaded and I have to go to the add-on folder and delete a folder called __pycache__, then back in Blender and hit f8 again.

Is there a way to prevent the cache from loading an obsolete version of my add-on (either by specifying it in my code, or by setting something in Blender)?

Comment: Rather than using F8 to reload all scripts, you can disable then enable your addon in the preferences. Blender will see that the addon file has been modified and reload it when you enable it, for single file addons this always works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can avoid that pycache folder by setting the `sys.dont_write_bytecode`
varaible to True.
Keep in mind that there won´t be any caches and caches at all for all your python files